# Род слова "коллега"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Не столько собственно вопрос, сколько вопрос-эмоция. Допустимо ли в устной речи формообразование "со своим коллегом"? Встречали ли вы подобное употребление? Я сегодня услышала впервые, к сожалению, из уст главного редактора крупной газеты в передаче по каналу РБК.

Comment: Ошибка устной речи. Быывает.

Comment: Тоже так сначала подумала. Но повторено было дважды.

Comment: Тяжелый случай. К сожалению, уровень культуры речи сейчас не зависит от занимаемой должности

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант, конечно, недопустимый. Но мало ли что может быть в ситуации спонтанной речи. Может, у говорящего всплыл в памяти дательный падеж множественного числа: *своим коллегам*. Хотел сказать одно, а получилось другое.

Если анализировать словоупотребление в Интернете, обнаруживается, что некоторые и Д.п. мн. ч. пишут с ошибкой: *сказать своим коллегом*. Отсюда недалеко и до *со своим коллегом*.

Comment: К сожалению, это не было похоже на оговорку, было повторено дважды. Мне подумалось: детей ругаем за ошибки, а главному редактору можно. Кстати, из его же речи: слово "Интернет" со всеми мягкими согласными.

Comment: Похоже, не все учились хорошо.

Answer (score 1):

Само слово "коллега" - сущ. общего рода. А кто он (мужчина или женщина) скажет местоимение или глагол в прош. вр.